# Actualizar datos de una tabla con resultados consulta

Tags: sql, transact-sql

Tengo dos tablas **artículos** y **articulos_nuevo** ambas con los mismos campos 'codigo' y 'nombre'.

Ambas tienen exactamente los mismo artículos con distinto código.
¿Como puedo actualizar los códigos de la tabla artículos con los de la tabla artículos_nuevo correspondiéndose con el campo nombre?

Como soy novato y algo cateto, he probado esto:

```
update articulos set codigo = (
   SELECT articulos_nuevo.CODIGO 
   FROM articulos_nuevo 
   INNER JOIN articulos ON articulos_nuevo.NOMBRE = articulos.NOMBRE
)
```

Pero no funciona porqué la subconsulta devuelve más de un registro.
¿Alguien me puede echar un cable ?

Comment: simplemente un comentario porque te veo con ganas de aprender, para que pienses, es código una llave primaria? en caso de serlo, debería ser una foreign key en la otra tabla? en caso  afirmativo, está declarado como tal en la descripción de la tabla?

Comment: Es llave primaria en ambas, ¿qué problema puede darme?

Comment: que por algún motivo cambie su valor en una tabla y en otra no, entonces tengas datos ilógicos. Pregunta: seguro que necesitas dos tablas y no una solo? y si metes una view? lo digo porque el código cambia mucho, y los parámetros también, tienes que meter algo para asegurarte de que el valor sea el mismo en ambas tablas. Yo buscaría la consistencia

Comment: Si, tienes razón, creo que buscaré otra manera mas segura de hacerlo, ya que estoy viendo que las repercusiones pueden ser muchas. De todas formas os lo agradezco mucho, ya que voy aprendiendo un montón.

Answer (score 1):

No es necesario recurrir a una subconsulta, con una sentencia simple que indique que campos comparten es suficiente

```
update articulos set codigo = b.codigo
FROM articulos_nuevo a
INNER JOIN articulos b ON a.NOMBRE = b.NOMBRE
```